# Calling Java functions from Haxe

Tags: java, haxe

I'm trying to call an external Java function from Haxe. How can I call a Java function that I've written from Haxe?

Java code:

```
public class ExternalClass{

    public static String myFunction(){ //this will be invoked from Haxe
        return "External Java function";
    }

}
```

Haxe main class:

```
class Main 
{
    public static function main() 
    {
        trace(myFunction()); //how can I properly access this Java method?
    }
}
```

Haxe extern class:

```
extern class Test
{
    public static function myFunction():String;
}
```

Comment: It's possible to do this using a Haxe "extern" class, but should the extern class be defined in the same folder as the Main class and ExternalClass? http://haxe.org/doc/java/externs

Comment: Should all 3 files be saved in the same source folder?

Comment: This question appears to be addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189417/access-external-javascript-libraries-using-haxe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interfacing with Java Functions in Haxe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602961/interfacing-with-java-functions-in-haxe)

Answer (score 2):

```
class Main 
{
    public static function main() 
    {
        trace(ExternalClass.myFunction()); //how can I properly access this Java method?
    }
}

extern class ExternalClass
{
    public static function myFunction():String;
}
```

Your external class should have the same name that your native java class.

Then you must call your function as a classic static one, prepending the class name to the function name.