# Interfacing with Java Functions in Haxe

Tags: java, haxe

I am trying to call an external Java function from Haxe using "extern".

**Haxe Code :**

```
extern class Ext
{
   public static function test():String;
}

class Sample 
{
   public static function main()
   {
       trace(Ext.test());
   }
}
```

**Java Code :**

```
public class Ext
{   
    public static String test()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Both Sample.hx and Ext.java files are in the same folder.

When I try to execute **haxe -main Sample -java Sample**, I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\ila5\Desktop\CPP>haxe -main Sample -java Sample
haxelib run hxjava hxjava_build.txt --haxe-version 3201 --feature-level 1
javac.exe "-sourcepath" "src" "-d" "obj" "-g:none" "@cmd"
src\haxe\root\Sample.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
                haxe.Log.trace.__hx_invoke2_o(0.0, haxe.root.Ext.test(), 0.0, new haxe.lang.DynamicObject(new java.lang.String[]{"className", "fileName", "methodName"}, new java.lang.Object[]{"Sample", "Sample.hx", "main"}, new java.lang.String[]{"lineNumber"}, new double[]{((double) (((double) (10) )) )}));
                                                            ^
  symbol:   class Ext
  location: package haxe.root
1 error
Compilation error
Native compilation failed
Error: Build failed
```

I would like to understand why the build failed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you might need to reference your Java code with `-lib` or something else?

But generally with Java target it's much simpler to just use a jar file.  By typing `haxe --help` you will see the relevant command listed, I have never had a need to hand write externs for the Java target.

`-java-lib <file>` : add an external JAR or class directory library

Comment: I understand that an external JAR can be added but I'd like to know why the "extern" method failed. Any ideas regarding that?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it fails is explained here

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/EHeoGN_Ppvg

I tried setting up with class paths and various options but did not get a solution, I think it's just a bit fiddly to do externs on the java target by hand.  Really it's better to use Java compiler to create jars and let haxe auto generate the externs unless you get an issue then report it to hxJava repository.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-java-lib`.

```
# build.sh
haxe Main.hx -main Main -java-lib javalib/ -java out
```

,

```
// ./Main.hx
import external.*;

class Main {
    public static function main() {
        trace(external.ExternalClass.myFunction());
    }
}
```

,

```
// ./javalib/external/ExternalClass.java
package external;

public class ExternalClass {

    public static String myFunction() {
        return "External Java function";
    }

}
```

,

`./javalib/external/ExternalClass.class` is the output of `javac ExternalClass.java`